# UWP/C#: Display back button if certain html file is opened in a WebView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm working to a porting from a Cordova app for the Universal Windows Platform. At this time, I basically created a container in which local html files are displayed (they were ported from the Cordova app too). Now, I would like to add a back button at the top-left corner of the window just like any UWP app. To do this, I use this instruction:

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
```

It works perfectly, but I want this button appears only when a certain html file is displayed into the webview. It should be a logic like this:

```
1) If certain_file.html is loaded
1.1) Show the back button
2) Else
2.1) Hide the back button
```

I'm working with Visual Studio and Visual C#. Do you have any idea about how can I do this thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [DOMContentLoaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.domcontentloaded) event of the webview to decide if the back button is displayed.

For example:

```xml
<WebView DOMContentLoaded="WebView_DOMContentLoaded" Source="ms-appx-web:///HTMLPage1.html"></WebView>
```

```cs
private void WebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Uri.LocalPath == "/HTMLPage1.html")
    {
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I tried this but it didn't work. This the code structure:
I have a file called MainPage.xaml, in which I added a WebView called "ononeWebContainer". I also assigned the DOMContentLoaded rule in this way "DOMContentLoaded="onomeWebContainer_DOMContentLoaded".
Then in the MainPage.xaml.cs I added a this into the MainPage public void after this.InitializeComponent(): onomeWebContainer.DOMContentLoaded += onomeWebContainer_DOMContentLoaded;
And finally, I created a private void (out of public void MainPage) with the code you explained.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `args.Uri.ToString() == "certain_file.html"` @IvanS. This line just was my sample. You need to use the practical Uri value to do judgement.

Comment: I tried with args.Uri.ToString() == "ms-appx-web:///myfile.html" and args.Uri.Host == "ms-appx-web:///myfile.html". I've also tried to create a new Uri string with the index file, and put the line "args.Uri != indexuri", but I got the same result. The same thing happens if I try to add the AppViewBackButton instruction to the DOMContentLoaded void without any if condition (so the button should appear with any content loaded into the WebView). May I forgot to add something to the WebView parameters or to the "public MainPage()"?

Comment: @IvanS. As I said in my above comment, my code just was a simple code sample. What you need to do is add some break points to debug your code and choose some appropriate properties value to do judgement. Anyway, please see my updated reply. I've made a complete code sample for you.

Comment: I debugged the code with breakpoints and I noticed that the problem is not the code itself, but the DOMContentLoaded void that is not triggered by the WebView. The program doesn't check the if condition. In fact, every single line I put into the public MainPage is triggered correctly. In addition to your code, i put "OnomeWebContainer.DOMContentLoaded += OnomeWebContainer_DOMContentLoaded;" and "WebView OnomeWebContainer = new WebView();" into the public MainPage.

Comment: Check my second post in topic.

Answer (score 0):

@Xavier Xie - MSFT This is the MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="Project_Onome.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Project_Onome"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <WebView x:Name="OnomeWebContainer"/>
    <WebView HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <WebView Source="ms-appx-web:///www/index.html"/>
    <WebView DOMContentLoaded="OnomeWebContainer_DOMContentLoaded"/>
</Grid>
```

And this is the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Project_Onome
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            WebView OnomeWebContainer = new WebView();
            OnomeWebContainer.DOMContentLoaded += OnomeWebContainer_DOMContentLoaded;
        }
    private void OnomeWebContainer_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Uri.LocalPath == "/security_auth.html")
        {
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I did not understand what you're doing. You added 4 WebView controls on XAML page and defined a WebView control ‘OnomeWebContainer’ in code-behind and registered `DOMContentLoaded` event for it. But I did not see that 'OnomeWebContainer' WebView navigates to 'security_auth.html'. The event will never be fired.

Comment: @Xavier Xie - MSFT Check my updated code, now everything works perfecly. The mistake, as you mentioned, was in the MainPage.xaml. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated code, now everything works perfectly!

1) MainPage.xaml

```
<WebView Name="OnomeWebContainer" Source="ms-appx-web:///www/index.html" DOMContentLoaded="OnomeWebContainer_DOMContentLoaded"></WebView>
```

2) MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void OnomeWebContainer_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Uri.LocalPath == "/www/security_auth.html")
        {
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Thanks to Xavier Xie for its help! :)